# Check if string is uppercase and numbers

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want to check if a string contains only uppercase letters and numbers. I have attempted to solve this using RegExp and what I have so far is:

```
Function CheckForInvalidChars()
    dim b
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "[A-Z_0-9]"    
    b = re.Test("eS")
    msgbox b
End Function
```

However the variable "b" returns true since I guess it finds a match in the "S" although I want that particular string to return false since not all letters are uppercase. How would I go about achieving this?

I have tried to do this with functions as well using `IsNumeric` but can't find a `IsUpperCase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want to match **whole** string using regex, you will usually end up using `^` and `$` to describe the start and end of string.

Also, just `[A-Z_0-9]` matches a single character.

Assuming you don't allow whitespaces, `^[A-Z_0-9]*$` would be the regex you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for providing an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If `UCase(s) <> s` then there is at least one lower case letter in the string `s`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andris is right, correct the regular expression as follows:

```
Function CheckForInvalidChars()
    dim b
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^[A-Z_0-9]*$"
    b = re.Test("eS")
    msgbox b
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to just `UCase` the string if you want to enforce uppercase letters. Then you can simplify the check to this:

```
Function CheckForInvalidChars(s)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^\w+$"
  CheckForInvalidChars = re.Test(s)
End Function

teststring = InputBox("Input something")
teststring = UCase(teststring)

WScript.Echo "" & CheckForInvalidChars(teststring)
```

The escape sequence `\w` matches word characters, i.e. uppercase letters, lowercase letters (ruled out due to the prior `UCase`), digits, and underscores. The `+` rules out empty strings by requiring at least one word character.